# Dialogflow returns an empty list of conversations

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, google-assistant-sdk

**Dialogflow returns an empty list of conversations**, without responses, however there are conversations in the agent

I´m developing a chatbot in dialogflow and need to get the conversations. When I try to get the list of conversations in the agent using the Python Client Library I don´t get any error but also any data. The iterable seems to be empty.

I have no authentication issue because I can get the list of intents and run other methods without error. I´m using the code in the google documentation with some changes:

```
from google.cloud import dialogflow_v2

# Create a client
client = dialogflow_v2.ConversationsClient()

# Initialize request argument(s)
parent = "projects/dermabot-dn9x"
filter = "(lifecycle_state = OPEN OR lifecycle_state = CLOSED)"

request = dialogflow_v2.ListConversationsRequest(
    parent=parent,filter = filter,
)

# Make the request
page_result = client.list_conversations(request=request)

# Handle the response
for response in page_result:
    print(response)
```

As you can see, I´ve forced the filter to retrieve all the conversations, but the filter has no effect, it isn´t the cause. I´ve also tryed with the async client because maybe there were a long running but I get also empty responses.

Anyone could help me?